# OutOfMemory exception while getting array of bytes

Tags: java, android, exception, memory, parse-platform

I need to send a video file to parse.com. Parse com is working with byte[].

I'm getting bytes array from video-file, and it's working fine. When i use huge video file like 100 mb it gives me:

```
05-25 16:27:48.934  23544-23544/com.ray.tapinto E/art﹕ Out of memory: Heap Size=192MB, Allocated=80MB, Capacity=512MB
05-25 16:27:48.934  23544-23544/com.ray.tapinto E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 134215692 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 111MB until OOM"
05-25 16:27:48.934  23544-23544/com.ray.tapinto E/CrashReporting﹕ ParseCrashReporting caught a OutOfMemoryError exception for com.ray.tapinto. Building report.
05-25 16:27:48.944  23544-23544/com.ray.tapinto E/CrashReporting﹕ Handling exception for crash
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 134215692 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 111MB until OOM
            at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:91)
            at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)
            at com.ray.tapinto.ui.activity.ViewPagerActivity.getBytes(ViewPagerActivity.java:523)
            at com.ray.tapinto.ui.activity.ViewPagerActivity.onActivityResult(ViewPagerActivity.java:494)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3877)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3931)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1408)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5721)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

usage:

```
...
     InputStream iStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(videoUri);
                    byte[] inputData = getBytes(iStream);
    ....
        private byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int bufferSize = 1024;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                int len = 0;
                while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
            }
```

Crashes on line             `byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);`

Saving file through parse

```
final ParseFile imageFile = new ParseFile(filename, imageData);

        imageFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if(e==null){
                }
            }
         }
```

**SOLUTION**
I found that parse.com allows to send only less than 10mb files, so it's supposed only for storing some small data like urls,thumbnails and so on

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with large files it is not good practice to load them into memory in one go. When you play a video you stream from the file to the media decoder. You don't load it all in memory before playing it.

Comment: i need to send a file to parse.com server. Parse com is only working with byte[]

Comment: Well show that bit of the code that uses their API. You probably (hopefully) can send in chunks of `byte[]`

Comment: added to the topic Parse part

Comment: I've watched sources of ParseFile- there is no way to send it in chunks. i will try to find some solution

Comment: they have poor community, so i can wait for answer for months

Answer (score 0):

There is a limitation on object file size in parse. 
The size limit of an object is 10MB

> The PFFile
>
> PFFile lets you store application files in the cloud that would
>   otherwise be too large or cumbersome to fit into a regular PFObject.
>   The most common use case is storing images but you can also use it for
>   documents, videos, music, and any other binary data (up to 10
>   megabytes).

for further details [The PFFile](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#files/iOS)

Answer (score -1):

You need to give your jvm more memory like -Xmx512m or even more -Xmx1g